# In JS6 web component how to find a slotted element's 3d transform context?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

In the new JS6 Web Component, you can use `<slot>` to include light dom's element into shaodow dom without losing its parent-child relationships in the light dom. If an element is slotted into a wrapper inside shadowRoot like this:

```
<Custom-Element>
    <shadowRoot>
       <div id="some-inner-wrapper">
           <slot name="some-slot"></slot>
       </div>
    </shadowRoot>

    <span slot="some-slot">Who is my context?</span>
</Custom-Element>
```

And now I'd like to set `transform-style: preserve-3d` on `<span slot="some-slot">`'s parent, should that property go to `<Custom-Element>`(its immediate parent), or to `<div id="some-inner-wrapper">`? And why so?

Answer (score 0):

The `preserve-3d` value shoud be set to the parent element.

In your case I suppose you want to position the slotted `<span>` element relative to the `<div id="inner-wrapper">`, so you need to apply `preserve-3d` to the the `<div>`.

See the example below:

```js
btn.onclick = () => { 
customElements.define( 'custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( {mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `
          <style>
            #some-inner-wrapper {
              display: inline-block ;
              padding: 10px ;
              background-color: rgb(255,0,0,0.5) ;
              transition: transform 1s ;
              transform-style: preserve-3d ; 
            }            
            #some-inner-wrapper:hover {
              transform: rotateY(55deg) ;           
            }
          </style>
          <div id="some-inner-wrapper">
             Horizontal <slot name="some-slot"></slot> Rotation
          </div>         
        `
  }
} ), btn.disabled=true
}
```

```css
span {
    display: inline-block ;
    transition: transform 1s ;
    padding: 20px ;
    border: 1px solid black ;
    background-color: yellow ;
    cursor: pointer ;
}
              
span:hover {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) ;
}
```

```html
<custom-element>
    <span slot="some-slot">Vertical Rotation</span>
</custom-element>

<div>
  <button id="btn">Upgrade</button>
```

Of course if you apply transformation rules to the Custom Element itself it could also work (because it's a parent too).

Code above was inspired by [W3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform-style).

Comment: This is wierd to find out, but slotted elements' stacking context is <html>, instead of `div#some-inner-wrapper`. The `preserve-3d` values works fine though.